# UserDefinedException & RunTimeException difference

Tags: java, exception, runtime, checked

if user defined exception extend class exception and becomes a checked exception, how come RunTimeException which also exends exception is different. I tried searching multiple forums, but still not able to understand whats the factor that treats RTE different than normal user defined exception - since both extend Exception class.

Comment: Since `RuntimeException` is part of the language it surely can be handled differently, just like `Serializable` is not just an ordinary interface but also handled in a special way.

Comment: so JVM treats RTE differently ?

Answer (score 0):

A user-defined exception can be:

- a checked type if it directly or indirectly extends `Exception`, or
- an unchecked type if it directly or indirectly extends `RuntimeException`.

(You could in theory extend `Throwable` or `Error` or a subclass of `Error`, but this is unnecessary, bad practice, and possibly dangerous.)

The JVM doesn't treat checked and unchecked types differently.  The different treatment is done by the Java compiler, which is why you get *compilation errors* if a check exception is not treated properly.  The rules are mandated by the Java *Language* Specification (JLS) not the runtime system.

---

> ...  how come `RunTimeException` which also extends `Exception` is different?

Because the JLS says it is.  The rules for checked and unchecked exceptions are part of the Java language, just like the grammar, the scoping rules, the type rules and so on.

Comment: that helps... JLS is the catch here that I was missing. Thank you so much for explaining this. Really appreciate your help.